# construct a sequence Sn that does not converge but its arithmetic mean converges to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series

I ran into a problem which requires me to construct a sequence call it Sn which does not converge, but its arithmetic mean call it An, converges to 0 as n-->infinity. im having a hard time solving this so i looked up the solution on a website called slader but im not convinced with the solution it's probably wrong because the Sn used is `1/n+1`which converges to one. [slader solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0CJ4.png). i left the image of the solution if anyone wants to see it. help would be appreciated thanks [original question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e48I.png). ive also left a picture of the original question. (it's part B im stuck on)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: thank you for the hint and welcome, ill make sure to use that next time. I apologize, its my first time using this website

Comment: To find what you want I would play around with sequences of $0$ and $1$ in such a way that $1$ appears less and less frequently as $n\to+\infty$. One such sequence could be $s_n=1$ if $n$ is a perfect square and $s_n=0$ otherwise, but I didn't do the math myself so I'm not sure. Hope it helps.

Comment: As you correctly assessed, the sequence $S_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$ in that image does not converge and I would not bother over complicating problems like this anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1,-1,1,-1,-1,...$ diverges, but
$\frac{1+(-1)+1+(-1)+...}{n}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: hello Derek luna, thank you for the answer. this might be a stupid question but i want to understand the intuition behind this sequence. im assuming that an even value results in one and an odd one results in -1. so if that goes to infinity doesnt that mean the sequence is either 1 or -1? and not infinity? (a stupid question some know but clarification would be appreciated)

Comment: For a sequence to diverge all is required is that the sequence does not converge.

Comment: Do you know the epsilon definition of convergence?

Comment: @DerekLuna I voted up but maybe you could write your sequence more formally: $x_n = (-1)^{n+1}$ and $ \frac 1n S_n = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k = \frac{(-1)^{n+1} +1}{2n}$

Comment: @PierreCarre I think it is great you added this as a comment to my answer. However, I feel the original answer is more helpful to those who would struggle with such a question.

Comment: @DerekLuna yes |Sn - s | < epsilon, thanks for the help guys

Comment: @DerekLuna I get you, and you are probably right. But remember that those who struggle with this question are very likely to commit some form of abuse of the symbol "$\cdots$" in the future!